# Python: continue loop from one point

Tags: python

I've just started a Python programming course and trying to go step by step.. I just created a little spanish - english reminder for myself and I am facing one diufficulty now. I am asking a question in english and need to translate it in spanish.. if the answer is correct I can go on however if the answer is false I would like to ask the qeustion again.. Here is my code so far, my problem is if I give a wrong answer the loop goes back to the first question.. Can you help me what shall I add just to repeat the question I failed to answer properly?

thank you,

```
while True:
    ask = raw_input('How are you? ')
    answer = str(ask)
    if answer == 'Que tal?':
        ask = raw_input(' Sorry, I have other programs ')
        answer = str(ask)
    if answer == 'Lo siento, pero ya tengo otros planes':
        ask = raw_input(' I am reading a book ')
        answer = str(ask)
    else:
        continue
```

Comment: It looks like you need to use multiple loops. I would use one loop for each questions, and `break` when you want to move on to the next one.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create list of `questions` and its `answers`. Save this details in any variable e.g. list.
2. Use `for loop` to iterate list items of question and use `raw_input()` to ask questions.
3. Check User Answer with correct or not by `if condition`.
4. If User Answer is wrong, then ask same question to User again.
5. If User Answer is correct, then ask next question.
6. Use `break` statement to come out from the while loop.

**Limitation:**
If User not give correct answer to any question then programme will ask same question again and again until User give correct answer.

Demo:

```
#- Create List of tuples which contains question and respective answer.    
questions = [("Question number one?", "one"), ("Question number two?", "two"),\
             ("Question number three?", "three")]

for i in questions:
    while 1:
        ans = raw_input(i[0])
        if ans==i[1]:
            print "Correct."
            break
        else:
            print "Wrong answer"
```

output:

```
infogrid@infogrid-vivek:~/workspace/vtestproject$ 
infogrid@infogrid-vivek:~/workspace/vtestproject$ python task4.py 
Question number one?test1
Wrong answer
Question number one?test1
Wrong answer
Question number one?one
Correct.
Question number two?two
Correct.
Question number three?test3
Wrong answer
Question number three?three
Correct.
```

---

**Multiple choice equations and answers.**

Demo:

```
#- Create List of tuples which contains question. optinons and  respective answer.
questions = [("Question number one?", ["a. one", "b. two", "c. three"], "a"),\
             ("Question number two?", ["a. one", "b. two", "c. three"], "b"),\
             ("Question number three?", ["a. one", "b. two", "c. three"], "c")
             ]

#- Set number of chances to solve each question.
chances = 3
#- Score. Plus one for each correct answer.
score = 0

for i in questions:
    print "-"*10
    for j in xrange(0, chances):
        print "Question:", i[0], "\n Options:", i[1]
        ans = raw_input("Enter option:")
        if ans==i[2]:
            print "Correct."
            score += 1
            break
        else:
            print "Wrong answer"


print "Your score: ", score
```

Output:

```
----------
Question: Question number one? 
 Options: ['a. one', 'b. two', 'c. three']
Enter option:b
Wrong answer
Question: Question number one? 
 Options: ['a. one', 'b. two', 'c. three']
Enter option:c
Wrong answer
Question: Question number one? 
 Options: ['a. one', 'b. two', 'c. three']
Enter option:b
Wrong answer
----------
Question: Question number two? 
 Options: ['a. one', 'b. two', 'c. three']
Enter option:b
Correct.
----------
Question: Question number three? 
 Options: ['a. one', 'b. two', 'c. three']
Enter option:s
Wrong answer
Question: Question number three? 
 Options: ['a. one', 'b. two', 'c. three']
Enter option:c
Correct.
Your score:  2
```